# Numba jitclass: parent class type as a class member

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, numba

Consider the class dof, and its child particleGroup:

```
class dof():
    def getVar(self):
        return self.var

spec = [
    ('var', float64[:]),
    ('C_s', float64[:]),          
]
@jitclass(spec)
class particleGroup(dof):
    def __init__(self, partRelease):
        self.var = np.array([partRelease.Q, partRelease.M[0], partRelease.M[1], partRelease.M[2], partRelease.B, partRelease.x[0], partRelease.x[1], partRelease.x[2], 0])
        self.C_s = np.copy(partRelease.C_s)
    def getC(self):
        return self.C_s
```

The details of partRelease object are not important.

The class *dof* is a python class as numba does not support inheritance of a jitclass. Thus, a deferred_type cannnot be used on it.

*dof* can be the parent of different child classes. I want the *dof* class to be used in another class, where I would be able to call the parent function *getVar()*.

**My question**: how to store an instance of this class (dof type or any of the child types) in another class? Which type to specify in the jitclass specification?

**Then**: Even if I can specify the parent class type, I suspect that the call to a python class will be expensive. Is there another way to do polymorphism efficiently, e.g. using templates instead of inheritance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer (at least to the 2nd question).

A solution is inspired from templates. It consists of not using inheritance, but distinct classes having the required common functions in their interface (here *getVar*).

```
spec = [
('var', float64[:]),
('C_s', float64[:]),          
]
@jitclass(spec)
class particleGroup():
    def __init__(self, val, valCs):
        self.var = np.array([val, val, val, val])
        self.C_s = np.array([valCs, valCs*2, valCs*3, valCs*4])
    def getC(self):
        return self.C_s
    def getVar(self):
        return self.var

spec = [
    ('var', float64[:]),   
]
@jitclass(spec)
class otherDofType():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = np.array([1.0, 0.0])
    def getVar(self):
        return self.var
```

If a class wants to use the common functions for any type of object, its definition can be encapsulated in a function:

```
def createUserClass(dofType, dofObject):
    dof_t = deferred_type()
    dof_t.define(dofType) 
    spec = [
        ('dof', dof_t),
    ]
    @jitclass(spec)
    class UserClass():
        def ___init__(self, dof):
            self.dof = dof
        def resetVar(self):
            a = dof.getVar()
            a[:] = 0   
    return UserClass(dofObject)
```

Then I can get and use instances of UserClass using for example:

```
particleGroupInstance = particleGroup(6.0, 2.0)
userObjectParticleGroup = createUserClass(particleGroup.class_type.instance_type, particleGroupInstance)
userObjectParticleGroup.resetVar()

otherDofTypeInstance = otherDofType()
userObjectOtherDofType = createUserClass(otherDofType.class_type.instance_type, otherDofTypeInstance)
userObjectOtherDofType.resetVar()
```

It is a bit heavy but works and should be faster than any solution based on inheritance...